# 8051 I/O programming logic/ how it works

Tags: microprocessor, latch, 8051, port, io

I'm new to microprocessors and trying to figure out how they work. I am quite confused about using the ports as inputs and outputs. It says that we should send '1' to the pin if we want to use it as input and '0' for output. What happens when a '0' comes to an input port as data? Will that port still remain as an input port? Will the output pin remain an output when '1' comes in?

I know that I'm missing something quite obvious but I couldn't figure it out, even though I have checked many different sources. I wonder how the pin circuit works and how it is affected by commands.

Comment: one register controls the direction of the port, another for the data

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I understand this for the input case.But, to make a port output I say MOV A, #00H MOV P2, A. Then lets say I want to output some random data like 25H. I would type MOV A, #25H MOV P2, A. How does the assembler decide which one goes which register, data or direction?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: unlike most modern microcontrollers, the 8051 does not have a Data Direction Register.  The outputs are open-collector, and can be used as inputs if you write Highs to the output register.

Comment: wow glad I never used one but good for I2C shared access.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 They were the best you could get during their day. Lots and lots of datasheet info, lots of application examples, etc. I modified my IBM Electronic Model 85 to use as a printer device back around 1982 with one. Worked perfect first time. I still have 100 of the 80C31's laying about in a nice box, here. Want one?

Comment: No doubt they were useful,  and are still being sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 8051 I/O port is different from most other microcontrollers.

The I/O ports (except P0) effectively have open collector outputs with internal pull-up resistors (P0 doesn't have pull-ups).

If you write a Zero to a port pin, the pin will be pulled to ground, and is definitely an output.

If you write a One to a port pin, the transistor driving the port will be turned off, so the pull-up resistor will pull the pin High.  In this state, the pin can be considered as a High output, or it can be used as an input, as an external device can pull the pin Low, when it will be read as a Zero.  If the external device does not pull the pin Low, it will be read as a High input.

Many other microcontrollers have Data Direction Registers that determine whether the pins can be used as inputs or outputs, and may have other registers to determine whether outputs are open collector or not, and whether pull-up or pull-down resistors are active when the pin is set as an input.

Comment: Thank you, and here is the point that I'm lost: "If you write a Zero to a port pin, the pin will be pulled to the ground, and is definitely an output." What happens if I want to output '1' through this pin. Won't the transistor be pulled off which makes this pin an input port? Or is the data transmitted in a different path which I don't know

Comment: @İlkerDemirel: if you write "1" to a port pin, the pull-up resistor will pull the pin High, and whatever you connect to that pin will see the High/1.  If you want to use the pin as an input, you MUST write a "1" to it, then it can be pulled to 0 by an external device.

Comment: @İlkerDemirel And if what Peter said still doesn't make sense, you need to spend some honest time studying transistors a little more. Once it makes sense, it will make a LOT of sense to you. You just need to climb over that barrier, so to speak. Then it's actually kind of simple.

Comment: @jonk Appreciate you all. At this point it is obvious that I must spend some time with transistors. But at least, now I know where is the trick.

Comment: @İlkerDemirel Good response, I think. I like to say that anyone serious about their work must develop an understanding that is at least two, but preferably three, emergent conceptual levels below the one they work at. For a C programmer, for example, this means machine code, activation frames, operating system design, and thunks (1 level) and also perhaps then ALU and general logic design (2nd level.) Sometimes, this must also include transistors (3rd level.) You'll enjoy knowing this detail when you acquire it. Best wishes!